# Problem with web3?

Tags: web3js, testrpc

When I try to get the list of `accounts` by using command line in `web3` console, it doesn't work. Let me show you the result in my machine. Please help me!
[image]

Comment: try web3.eth.getAccounts(callback(error, result){ ... })

Comment: What do you have in '...' ?

Comment: your callback exp web3.eth.getAccounts((err, acc) => {
    console.log(acc);
});

Comment: You are using version 1.0 version of web3, the command you used don't return the accounts, @BadrBellaj's answer would work

Comment: Before all these commands, I forgot this `npm init` in order to create the package.json file. Now it works. Do you think that it solves my problem ?

Comment: @Mansour Actually, I'm using version 1.0.0 of web3

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it will help you please follow given steps.

1-Run Given command and replace datadir(chaindata) with your datadir.

geth --identity "LocalTestNode" --rpc --rpcport 9090 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir=./chaindata/ --port 30303 --nodiscover --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --networkid 1999

2-run given code

```
var express = require('express');   
var Web3 = require('web3');   
var app = express();

// This responds with "Hello World" on the homepage
app.get('/getAccounts', function (req, res) {

let provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9090"); 
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
res.send(web3.eth.accounts);
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

3- call given get api
    http://localhost:8081/getAccounts

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange. Please explain a bit more what your answer is supposed solve and explain why it solves the problem.

Comment: @vikas balyan I got this error:
ReferenceError: eth is not defined

Comment: @LauriPeltonen thanks i have update my answer and i think now it solves the problem.